# what is the problem with my code python web scraping Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to get the url links from an HTML code. I have made a list for these
. Also tried  `urls.append(link("a")['href'])`:

```
urls = []

soup = get_soup(url)

for link in soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'lvtitle'}):
    urls.append(link['href'])
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<h3 class="lvtitle">
<a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/BMW-X5-E53-Workshop-Service-Manual-2000-2006-Download/193025571580?hash=item2cf1387afc:g:dUUAAOSw7kxdLePk" 
class="vip" title="Click this link to access BMW X5 E53 Workshop Service Manual 2000 - 2006 Download">
BMW X5 E53 Workshop Service Manual 2000 - 2006 Download</a>
</h3>
```

Ii run it and I get `KeyError: 'href'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `link` is a `<h3>` tag and not the `<a>`.

Try this:

```py
for h3 in soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'lvtitle'}):
    link = h3.contents[0]
    urls.append(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for link in soup.find_all(('h3', {'class': 'lvtitle'})):
    urls.append(link.find('a')['href'])
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable